# ajax call inside lambda function does not work

Tags: lambda

I have a lambda function and I am trying to call an external service via ajax call and get the result back and then return the reult in the return function of the lambda. Here is my code:

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
var token = event.authorizationToken;
 var http = require('https');
           var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

switch (token.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'allow':


        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn,xmlHttp.responseText[0].title));
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
xmlHttp.send(null);

        break;

    default:
        callback("Error: Invalid token"); 
 }
};

var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource,res) {
var authResponse = {};

authResponse.principalId = principalId;
if (effect && resource) {
    var policyDocument = {};
    policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; // default version
    policyDocument.Statement = [];
    var statementOne = {};
    statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; // default action
    statementOne.Effect = effect;
    statementOne.Resource = resource;
    policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
    authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
}

// Can optionally return a context object of your choosing.
authResponse.context = {};
authResponse.context.stringKey = res;
return authResponse;
```

}

When I try the above code I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

So apparently lambda does not support either XMLHttpRequest  or ajax.
Is there any way I can make an ajax call and get the response back(preferebly in json) in lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Of course Lambda supports XMLHttpRequest! :)

You just need to install it:

`npm i xmlhttprequest`

And then import it in your lambda function:

`var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`